# When I use A JPA Query's getResultList(), are the results detached or managed?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When I have a JPA Query that I call .getResultList(), It gives me back a List of objects. Are the objects in that list managed or detached? That is, do I have to worry about merging or persisting them later if I make changes to them, or will those changes be picked up automatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the objects returned from `.getResultList()` are managed.

When you made changes on the managed  objects, you do not worry about merging as those changes will be picked up by the `EntityManager` automatically.

The managed objects will become detached when the `EntityManager` that is used to load that object is [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#close%28%29), [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) or [detach()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29). Detached objects are not manged anymore and you should do merging to let the `EntityManager` pick up the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought they would be attached, but it seemed like they were detached. It turns out that I was mistakenly creating a second EntityManager so it seemed that they were detached.

Comment: Do you have to .commit() the changes or is that automatic too?

Comment: I believe it's automatic, however it shouldn't hurt to do so.

Comment: Answer from @steliyan-georgiev works for me. If the EntityManager is run without transaction, returned results is not managed.

Answer (score 3):

They will be managed if you are currently within a transaction, but if you are not (e.g. if you have annotated your trnasction with TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED or TransactionAttributeType.NEVER) your entities will not be managed.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience the getResultList() return values are Attached.  That is, you do not have to manually persist them if you make modifications to them within the same transaction.