# JPA: Native queries with lifecycle callbacks in entity listener

Tags: java, spring, jpa, openjpa

**TL;DR:** Why aren't the results of my call to `query.getSingleResult()` or `query.getResultList()` being managed by the persistence context? I'm getting the query objects from the entity manager so they absolutely should be, no? This question indicates it should: [When I use A JPA Query's getResultList(), are the results detached or managed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153995/when-i-use-a-jpa-querys-getresultlist-are-the-results-detached-or-managed)

So I am using OpenJPA in Spring and have some entities listened on by an entity listener of course. The entity listener listens for two lifecycle callbacks: pre-persist and post-load. Pre-persist goes through just fine, but post-load never happens I imagine because I am using native queries in my repository (via the `@Query` annotation on my JpaRepository).

**Example:**

```
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {
    @Query(value = "...", nativeQuery = true)
    private MyEntity someNativeQuery(String name, String id);
}
```

So I thought perhaps I should "implement" this repository to call the entity manager directly via `em.createNamedQuery("...", MyEntity.class)` and annotate my entity with the `@NamedQuery` so that the object returned is being managed by the persistence context. This is of course a hypothesis of mine, so please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong since the rest of the question then becomes kind of pointless.

Issue now is I was using native queries because I want to call some DB specific functions that aren't SQL standard, so the named queries didn't work out whatever I did. (i.e. using `func('db_fun', parameters)` or `function('db_fun', parameters)` would throw parsing exceptions when getting data) so I decide to use the `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation on my entity with the old native query.

Once again this failed to trigger the post-load lifecycle callback even though it gets the object from the DB. What do?

**Entity**

```
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(name = "...", query = "...", resultClass = MyEntity.class)})
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

**Entity listener**

```
public class MyEntityListener {
    @PostLoad
    public postLoadFunction(MyEntity myEntity) {
        ... //never reached :(
    }
}
```

**Repository Implementation**

```
public class MyEntityRepositoryImpl {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    MyEntity myProblematicQuery(Object parameters, ...) {
        TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = em.createNamedQuery("myNamedNativeQuery", MyEntity.class).setParameter(...);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```